# Add Web API project to an existing ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I created an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm trying to expose functions as a REST API. 
I know it is probably better using asp. Net WEB API.

My question is can I add web api to my existing mvc application or do I have to completely create new web api project.

Or can both be functional in one project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Web API to your existing Asp MVC project.

Add via nuget:
* Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2

Also, ensure you have a WebAPIConfig class in your App_Start with the following:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```